# Why is Google Chrome on Android rendering my table different than on desktop or in Firefox?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I have deployed a website on wordpress with a predefined theme and some plugins for buying tickets online for events.

Now my problem is a table, showing a list of all the events, which gets displayed horrofully wrong on google chrome on android devices. In Firefox on my android phone everything looks fine. Here are two pictures showing the website (URL: https://kuba-halle.de/tickets) in chrome and firefox:

Chrome: [image: table view in chrome]

Firefox: [image: table view in Firefox]

I tried to look at the website in Google Chrome on my desktop computer, but there the table renders fine when i rescale the window.

I use "normal" media queries to assign different css rules for the table e.g. like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.we-table-lisst .we-table td h3{ margin-bottom:15px;}
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
.we-table-lisst .we-table td h3{ margin-bottom: 2px;}
}
```

Thank you for any help with the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dosn't render the same as other browsers. also try this for your media query:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! So how can I apply different css-rules to chrome on android then? Is 600px a better width for switching between layouts?

Comment: Are you using:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Yes, except it says: initial-scale:1">. Rest is identical.